# Hex vs. decimal representation of numbers in registers and operands

Tags: assembly, x86

I have had trouble with conceptually understanding assembly language. And I would like to clarify if I am on the right track.

For example, lets say the register `eax` contains the hex value 0x000000FF and the instruction is `add eax, 44d`. All I essentially would be doing is adding 44 to 255, which is what FF is. And the result would be 0x0000012B matching the format of what was already in the eax register.  I would like clarification on this thanks.

Comment: Nate, everything is stored as binary, just ones and zeroes, anything else is representation, you can represent the same value as binary, decimal, octal, hex, or any other base, but they are all nothing but bits.

Comment: okay so the ff would be stored as 1111 1111 and I would then add additional bits for the addition so in this case it would have to be 100101011 and thus converting that to hex it would be x12B

Comment: Hardware and software don't see hex or dec, they only see bits, human beings invented hex and dec to make life easier.

Comment: So as I am understanding it, the machine would only see the 1's and 0's

Comment: We, developers, tell computers to display values as decimal, hex or ASCII chars because we can understand that, so computers take bits and **represent** them according to our needs.

Comment: Okay I think that clears things up for me some. Thanks!

Comment: Saying "8086" instead of "x86" means you're talking about the original first-gen 16-bit only CPU.  But you're talking about EAX, so you should say "x86"

Comment: BTW, to add to that `add` .. it not only produces value 299 in `eax`, but it also sets flags in flag register, for example CF=0, SF=0, PF=1 (even number of ones in least significant byte, the fifth one is out of LSB and doesn't count to PF) and ZF=0 (I'm not sure about others). So it will modify bits at two places in CPU, target register, and flag register. It's worth to pay attention which instructions do affect flags and how, when you read about them in instruction reference guide, as on x86 the flags can be handy (like not doing `cmp eax,0` after `add`, as you know the ZF is already set).

Comment: Both Windows and macOS have a calculator app. I assume Linux distributions have something similar. Open it, switch to "Programmer" mode, and enter a numeric value. Then, switch between "Hexadecimal", "Decimal", and "Binary" modes. Note that the *value* is exactly the same, it is just *represented* differently in each of these modes. Internally, a computer always uses a "binary" representation, but because *all representations are identical*, you can think of the values being represented however you want. Programmers often find hex more convenient than binary. For one thing, it's shorter!

Answer (score 1):

The numbers has no "numeral system" at all. They have only value.

The numeral system (hexadecimal, decimal, octal, binary, etc) is only a writing system. It has meaning only if the number has to be written on some information carrier - sheet of paper, computer screen, memory cell, etc.

Changing the numeral system, does not change the value of the number.

So, you can write the number in different numeral systems and it will have the same value, regardless that it seems to be different. You only need to read it differently.

In assembly language, the hexadecimal system is preferred because it allows very easy (mentally) converting to and from binary (the system CPU use to write numbers in the memory). That is why most debuggers will display the numbers in hex.